# Javafx animation playing error

Tags: multithreading, nullpointerexception, javafx

I will try to tell here the short story: I have some animations that are loaded on the screen. When they one of them is played to do a transition this error appears. I don't know what to do from here.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I used also something like this, because I thought here might be the problem:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                instance.getChildren().addAll(path,polygon,text);
                instance.toBack();
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance! And if you need extra info I will be glad to update/edit the post.

EDIT:
after some more digging I found this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.sun.prism.paint.Paint
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.setFillPaint(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.updatePGShape(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.impl_updatePeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Polygon.impl_updatePeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this was caused by:

```
polygon.setFill(color);
```

where polygon is a *javafx.scene.shape.Polygon* and color is *javafx.scene.paint.Color*, but retrieved from a json file. After this I changed to:

```
polygon.setFill(Color.web(color.toString()));
```

Now all seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are modifying the scene graph off of the JavaFX application thread, though it is impossible to say without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't have a mcve because actually I don't know exactly from where this problem comes. And the error doesn't help me that much. The only thing that I'm doing that's related to a thread is loading a progress bar. Though, thanks for reply and I will try to come back with more information.